# My site can't be scrolled on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, css, coffeescript, sass, parallax

I believe it might have to do with the css. But maybe it's due to the inclusion of the parallax javascript library.

The site is http://www.mediachicken.com

The SASS is here

```
@import "compass/css3";
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */

html,
body {
  padding-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  z-index: 10;
}


.post-meta {
    .list-inline {
        li:first-child {
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
        li:last-child {
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
        li {
            font-style: italic;
            padding-right: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
        }
    }
}


a.anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -65px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.container .credit {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.mediachicken-svg {
    max-width: 325px;
    min-width: 36px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 7px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -160px;
    z-index: 200;
}

.header-spacer {
    height: 340px;
    &.sticky {
        height: 410px;
    }
}


.post-header {

}

#navigation {
    width: 648px;
    .container-fluid, .collapse {padding: 0;}
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    @include transition-property(box-shadow);
    @include transition-duration(.5s);
    &.sticky {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
    }

    /* Nav bar items */
    ul.nav {
        li a {
            border-left: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        }
    }

}

.postloop {
    h2 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}

.post-header {

}

.post-body {
    .post-meta {
        font-style: italic;
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        border-radius: 8px;
    }
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 1em;
        text-indent: 0em;
    }
    ul li:before {
        content: "\2014 \020";
    }
}

.post-footer {

}


.adsbygoogle {
  float: right;
}
```

And here is the Coffeescript source that is loading to place the menu bar at the top of the screen when the user scrolls far enough.

```
$ ->
  nav = $("#navigation")
  previous = 0
  tick = 0
  frozen = 0

  minifyNav = ->
    s = 36
    $("#navigation").addClass "sticky"
    $(".header-spacer").addClass "sticky"

  handleScroll = ->
    scroll = window.pageYOffset
    navPos = $("#navigation").offset().top
    distance = scroll - navPos

    if (distance < previous - tick or distance > previous + tick)
      if (-distance >= 36 and -distance < 330)
        previous = distance
        s = -(distance)*.90
      else if scroll <= frozen
        if $("#navigation").hasClass "sticky"
          $("#navigation").removeClass "sticky"
          $(".header-spacer").removeClass "sticky"
      else if -distance <= 0 and not $("#navigation").hasClass "sticky"
        frozen = 340
        previous = frozen
        minifyNav()


  $("#navigation").width $(".container").width()
  $(window).resize ->
    $("#navigation").width $(".container").width()

  $(window).scroll ->
    handleScroll()
```

any ideas what might be causing it to not scroll? When I scale the web page down all the way on my computer, it scrolls just fine. Also, my menu bar doesn't seem to be expanding when I use the button in the mobile view. Not sure why that's happening either, but it might be a stupid error on my part. I'm more worried about the (lack-of) scrolling.

Comment: I haven't looked extensively at your code, but it might have to do with this:: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009577-CH1-SAFARI_ON_IPAD_READINESS_CHECKLIST-4__MODIFY_CODE_THAT_RELIES_ON_CSS_FIXED_POSITIONING

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the scroll issue is the lack of a #skrollr-body id on an element in your page on mobile. Make sure thats included and has a min-height. [Check out the Skrollr docs on that here](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#what-you-need-in-order-to-support-mobile-browsers).

As for your menu button, there doesn't seem to be any event listener on your toggle. Add a click/touch event to apply and remove the toggling classes.

Also, this is an issue with any mobile device width, and not iOS or iPhone specific. I was able to duplicate the issue in Chrome desktop.